# Is there a way to return output that is associated to a specific field in SQL if all of the criteria equals a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to pull data from a Database. The data I am querying is associated with Purchase Orders and Purchase Order Lines. I want to only pull the Purchase orders associated only if every Purchase order line has a status of filled and anything else disregard. How would some code translate this information into SQL.

```
PO's|POLine's|Status
===================
1   |0       |F
1   |1       |F      <-----PO is completely filled
1   |2       |F            and should be returned.
1   |3       |F
====================
2   |0       |O
2   |1       |F
2   |2       |F      <-----PO is not completely filled 
2   |3       |O            and shouldn't be returned.
2   |4       |P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably to count the number of PO Lines that aren't fulfilled, and make sure it's 0:

```
SELECT po
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY po
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN status != 'F' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from table t1
where not exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.po=t2.po and
                                          t2.Status!='F')
```

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=adc30ef8925f1129527ea4dd8c4b020b)